# File upload and download from Filenet

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet

We are working on integration Dynamics CRM with Filenet. This requires support of the following two scenarios:

1. Upload a document in Filenet through web service and retrieve a unique URL for uploaded document from Filenet
2. Download document through unique URL of Filenet

Development platform is .NET.

Any ideas about the integration mechanism for same? Is there any webservice exposed by Filenet which we can consume for above 1 & 2 requirements?

Answer (score 4):

The url's in filenet are always in a fixed format, so that's not difficult.

```
http://P8_client_server_name/application_name:port/getContent?objectStoreName={84A4A727-37E2-4994-B060-8531FAF75612}&objectType=document&id={559946a8-2007-4096-AC67-773A8540AE6}
```

So call the getContent page with the parameters opbjectstore name or ID, objecttype and the id of the document.

Here [is an article about the format of the url's it should help you for the downloading part.](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.doc/ae_help/ae_admin/aeadm_access_objects_via_url.htm)

About the [uploading](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSNW2F_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.ce.doc/document_procedures.htm#document_procedures__doc_procedures_create),

Here are some API samples about sorting a document in the content engine. With the Id created were you can construct the url to return to the client.

Comment: a downvote without a comment? that's cold! Even the url to the official ibm documentation contains .net sample code.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previous response, for downloading you can also [construct a URL for IBM Content Navigator](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEUEX_2.0.2/com.ibm.developingeuc.doc/eucbd001.html) like this

http://myserver.mycompany.com:9080/navigator/bookmark.jsp?desktop=AccountsPayable&repositoryId=AP_P8_System&docid=30dd879c-ee2f-11db-8314-0800200c9a66&template_name=APtemplate&version=released

where

> **desktop**
>    Specifies which desktop to log in to.​ Specify the ID that is
>   displayed for the desktop in the ID column on the Desktops tab in the
>   administration tool. Format: desktop=desktop_ID
>
> **repositoryId**
>   Specifies the server to log in to.​ Specify the ID that
>   is displayed for the server in the ID column on the Repositories tab
>   in the administration tool. Format: repositoryId=repository_ID
>
> **docid**
>  The system-generated identification number for the document.
>   Uses the template_name value as the prefix to this folder ID. Format:
>   docid=document_ID
>
> **template_name**
>  Document, Folder, or the name of the custom document
>   class or item type. Format: template_name=template_name
>
> **version**
>    current, released, or a specific version number. Format:
>   version=version_number
>
> **vsld**
>   The IBM FileNet® P8 version series object, which is the Globally
>   Unique Identifier (GUID), that is associated with the document.
>   Format: vsld=GUID_number

Using Navigator menu:

> You can get URLs for documents or folders when you select the item and
>   click Actions > View link.